# Node content in panels vs. configuration in code

Tags: panels, features

I am trying to keep most of the configuration in code (and separating content and configuration). When I have a panel that is supposed to contain a content from for example a node, I would like to be able to export that setup somehow so that I can be sure it would work also on the other page. So it shouldnt be a node id, not either node title (so from my point of view, this [help](http://drupal.org/node/207381) doesnt qualify).

The way I did it is somewhat complicated, but allows me to keep all config in code while happily creating the content separately. I am posting a writeup my colleague did to convince me i am doing it too much complicated. Yet, I cant think of a better way.

1. Create taxonomy vocabulary with terms: top, middle, bottom.
2. Create custom node-type called panel content to which you assign terms from vocabulary from pt 1
3. Create a view that takes term from vocab from pt 1 as an argument.
4. Place this view inside frontpage panel and hardcode the argument depending on region.

Am I missing some point here? Would there be a better way to it?
Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't entirely see how your solution allows you to embed specific nodes?

Comment: step 2 could have been a nodetype with taxonomy, for some reason i used entities in that project. So to answer your question - specific node would be selected by taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

One could

1. Use [Fieldable panels panes](http://drupal.org/project/fieldable_panels_panes), which can replace the custom entity you use, and put content directly into the pane.
2. Configure the view to find nodes with a certain tag. Tag the node that should show up. Require the tag to be [uniquely applied](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field) if only a single node is allowed.